# Trait `Encodable` is private

Tags: rust

I have problem making my generic `InMemoryColumn<T>` serializable. It complains that the 'Encodable' and 'Decodable' trait is private but I see it's public [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize/blob/master/src/serialize.rs). How can I implement these traits so I can encode and decode the underlying `Vec<T>`.

Here's the code with the import:

```
extern crate bincode;
extern crate libc;
extern crate "rustc-serialize" as rustc_serialize;

use rustc_serialize::serialize::{Encodable,Decodable};
//import other libs

pub struct InMemoryColumn<T> {
    name: String,
    data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T: Eq + Ord + Hash + Encodable + Decodable> InMemoryColumn<T> {
    fn save(&self, tbl_name: &str) {
        //encode self.data and write to disk 
    }

    fn load(path: &str, name: &str) -> Result<InMemoryColumn<T>,String> {
        //decode from disk and populate InMemoryColumn<T>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Encodable` and `Decodable` traits are only public relative to the `serialize` module. [That module is private though](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L26). As you can see in the [`mod.rs` file](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L23-24), `Encodable` and `Decodable` are re-exported directly in the `rustc_serialize` crate. You can therefor use the `Encodable` and `Decodable` traits as follows:

```
use rustc_serialize::{Encodable,Decodable};
```